# IOS 10 notification event not firing with distribution profile in cordova app in background mode

Tags: ios, cordova, ios10

I upgraded my xcode to version 8 and I have an I phone 6, I created an app with cordova plugin push and it works fine when I run it with development profile and certificates, however when I run the same app with the distribution profile then in IOS 10, the notification event in not getting triggered when the app is in background.

Comment: I also have this problem with the iphone 5s, using iOS 10.0.2 and phonegap-push-plugin 1.8.2 with an older cordova version (5.2.0)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: partially yes, we had to set the content-available param to 1 inside the aps object and then some of the phones iphone 6+, 5 that were not receiving the notifications started receiving the notifications, however some phones still do not receive the notifications which are running on ios 10